# How to Give Two Forms to JCombobox Items in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, mapping, jcombobox

i am stuck with a new problem, don't know if this works but here i have list of `JCombobox` as follow.

```
JCombobox comboBox = new JComboBox();
    comboBox.addItem("UserName");
    comboBox.addItem("Password");
    comboBox.addItem("DLNo 20 b");
    comboBox.addItem("DLNo 20 b");
```

i want to print my database `column names` which are more than 40!

when i select the `Combobox` it must internally print my custom item here.

Here i tried with this code but i am not satisfied with this

```
            if(comboBox.getSelectedIndex()==0)
            {
                System.out.println("U_NAME");
            }

            if(comboBox.getSelectedIndex()==1)
            {
                System.out.println("P_NAME");   
            }

            if(comboBox.getSelectedIndex()==2)
            {
                System.out.println("DL_NO_20_b");   
            }

            if(comboBox.getSelectedIndex()==3)
            {
                System.out.println("DL_NO_20_b");   
            }
```

is there any better way to over come this, like `mapping objects`

Comment: use ItemListener for unique selectedItem, ActionListener for each selection

Answer (score 1):

You could create a class ComboBoxItem with a name- and a columnName-attribute.
Use instances of this class for the ComboBox.

In the ComboBoxItem-class, overwrite the toString()-method to return the name, so it gets displayed as wished in the ComboBox. Add a getColumnName()-method to return the columnName, so you could invoke getSelectedItem().getColumnName().